# Find minimum and maximum in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I was trying to solve the question where I need to write a function that return the minimum and maximum of an integer array of size N in MIPS language I tried but every time it return the minimum and maximum I have put as default and I couldn't figure out why
my code is:

```
.data
en: .asciiz "Enter N"
val: .asciiz "enter the values: "
min: .asciiz "the min is: "
max: .asciiz "the max is: "

.text
li $v0 4
la $a0 en
syscall

li $v0 5
syscall

blez $v0 End

move $t0 $v0 #t0 contain N

li $v0 9
mul $a0 $t0 4
syscall

move $t1 $v0 #s1 contain the array

li $v0 4
la $a0 val
syscall

li $t2 1
 #filling the array
Fill:
bgt $t2 $t0 endFill
li $v0 5
syscall
sw $v0 ($t1)
addi $t2 $t2 1
addi $t1 $t1 4
j Fill

endFill:
mul $t3 $t0 4
sub $t1 $t1 $t3

move $a0 $t0
move $a1 $t1

jal minmax
move $t2 $v0 #max
move $t3 $v1 #min

#print the min and max
li $v0 4
la $a0 min
syscall
li $v0 1
move $a0 $t3
syscall

li $v0 4
la $a0 max
syscall
li $v0 1
move $a0 $2
syscall

j End



minmax:
move $s0 $a0 #s0 contain N
move $s1 $a1 #s1 contain the array

li $s2 0 #for the loop
li $s3 0 #for the max
li $s4 23456 #for the min

Loop:
bge $s2 $s0 EndLoop
lw $s5 ($s1) #s5 contain the element of the list
bgt $s5 $s3 tomin
move $s3 $s5
j tomin
tomin:
blt $s5 $s4 goagain
move $s4 $s5
j goagain
goagain:
addi $s2 $s2 1
addi $s1 $s1 4
j Loop
EndLoop:
move $v0 $s3
move $v1 $s4
jr $ra

End:
li $v0 10
syscall
```

I tried printing the value of the min and max (s4 and s3 in the function minmax in the part EndLoop) and there it also show me the default values I have put so I guess it didn't enter the loop but I can't figure out why
I'm still new to this language so I'm struggling a bit
thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't break questions (change to another question) by editing.

Comment: @MikeCAT ah sorry I didn't know this wasn't allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in this part is reversed.

```
bgt $s5 $s3 tomin
move $s3 $s5
j tomin
tomin:
blt $s5 $s4 goagain
move $s4 $s5
j goagain
goagain:
```

`$s3` is for the *maximum* value, so you will want to skip updating `$s3` if the candidate value is *smaller than* `$s3`.

In the same way, you will want to skip updating the *minimum* value `$s4` if the candidate value is *larger than* `$s4`.

Therefore, `bgt` and `blt` in this part should be swapped.

(whether to update when the candidate value equals to `$s3` or `$s4` is not a large issue)

Comment: thank you so much for helping! I don't know how I missed this but now it show that the max and min is 1 in the final output like it didn't keep on entering the loop can you help me in this part too please. (I edited the post based on what you gave me and my new output)

Comment: @Lou The minimum value looks correct in my QtSpim after adding `,` between each operands and adding `main:` after `.text`. You looks printing `$2` instead of `$t2` as the maximum value.

Comment: omg thank you so much it worked! I need to pay more attention to this stuff thank you so much again!